# como pasar un parámetro a una consulta whereExist de Laravel

Tags: laravel, where

Quisiera pasar un valor determinado a un consulta en laravel que tiene incluida una función de búsqueda dentro de ella.

este el ejemplo de lo que estoy haciendo:

```
$input = $request->all();

$muestreos = MuestreoGeneral::whereBetween('fecha', [$date_inicio, $date_fin])
        
           ->whereExists(
        
                         function ($query, $input) {
                            $query->select(DB::raw(10))
                                  ->from('aprobacion_banco')
                                  ->whereRaw('muestreo_general.aprobacion_banco_id = aprobacion_banco.id')
                                  ->whereRaw('aprobacion_banco.banco_sangre_id', $input['banco_sangre_id'] ); 
    })->get();
```

Pero me da error en este punto de la función: `function ($query, $input)`.

Alguien me puede dar una idea de como pasarle parámetros a esta función

Answer (score 0):

la solucion que encontre fue la siguiente:

```
$muestreos = MuestreoGeneral::whereBetween('fecha', [$date_inicio, $date_fin])->where('terminado', 0)->orderBy('fecha', 'asc')
                                                    ->WhereExists(
                                                        function ($query) use ($input) {
                                                            $query->select(DB::raw(10000))
                                                                ->from('aprobacion_banco')
                                                                ->whereRaw('muestreo_general.aprobacion_banco_id = aprobacion_banco.id')
                                                                ->where('aprobacion_banco.banco_sangre_id', '=', $input['banco_sangre_id'] );

                                                        })->get();
```

Adicione `function ($query) use ($input)` y listo